# How to override a Flask blueprint URL?

Tags: python, oauth, flask, mediawiki-extensions

I am using [`flask-mwoauth`](https://github.com/valhallasw/flask-mwoauth) to create a simple application in Flask using OAuth authentication on Mediawiki (and Wikipedia in particular).

`flask-mwoauth` is a blueprint that provides some convenience methods to interact with Mediawiki Extensions:OAuth and adds the following URIs:

- `/login` - runs the OAuth handshake and returns the user to `/`

  - `/login?next=/someurl` will return the user to `/someurl`
- `/logout` - clears the users' access tokens

  - `/logout?next=/someurl` will return the user to `/someurl`
- `/oauth-callback` - callback from MW to finish the handshake

The users' OAuth key and secret are stored in the session.

I would like to be able to create custom responses for some of this custom URIs. Take for example `/logout`, the definition of the response in very simple ([`__init__.py#L56`](https://github.com/valhallasw/flask-mwoauth/blob/master/flask_mwoauth/__init__.py#L56)):

```py
@self.bp.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session['mwo_token'] = None
    session['username'] = None
    if 'next' in request.args:
        return redirect(request.args['next'])
    return "Logged out!"
```

I would like to define in my application the route `/logout` with a custom response (for example, rendering a template), however if I use the blueprint then the route `@app.route("/logout")` is ignored.

What I would like to know if it is possible to "extend" the blueprint in the sense that I can define a route `/logout` in my app, call the original method from the blueprint and then serve a customized response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely redefine behavior of route the best way is override `MWOAuth` class. Here an example which works:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_mwoauth import MWOAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)


class MyMWOAuth(MWOAuth):
    def __init__(self,
                 base_url='https://www.mediawiki.org/w',
                 clean_url="Deprecated",
                 default_return_to='index',
                 consumer_key=None,
                 consumer_secret=None,
                 name="Deprecated"):
        # I skipped other rows. It's just an example
        self.bp = Blueprint('mwoauth', __name__)
        # By the way you can customize here login and oauth-callback
        @self.bp.route('/logout')
        def logout():
            # your custom logic here...
            return "My custom logout"


mwoauth = MyMWOAuth(consumer_key='test', consumer_secret='test')
app.register_blueprint(mwoauth.bp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Let's open `/logout`. You will see `My custom logout`.
As you can see registration of BluePrint routes takes place in `init` method of `MWOAuth`.

The second way is to use [request callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/deferredcallbacks/). Here an example which demonstrates the change in the body of the response after logout.

```
from flask import g, request


def after_this_request(f):
    if not hasattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks'):
        g.after_request_callbacks = []
    g.after_request_callbacks.append(f)
    return f


@app.after_request
def call_after_request_callbacks(r):
    for callback in getattr(g, 'after_request_callbacks', ()):
        callback(r)
    return r


@app.before_request
def before_logout():
    @after_this_request
    def after_logout(response):
        # check if called route == '/logout'
        # in our case response.data == 'Logged out!'
        # see: https://github.com/valhallasw/flask-mwoauth/blob/master/flask_mwoauth/__init__.py#L48
        if request.url_rule.endpoint == 'mwoauth.logout':
            # custom logic here...
            # for example I change data in request
            response.data = 'Data from after_logout'
```

Let's open `/logout`. You will see `Data from after_logout`.

Hope this helps.